# Disable Request.Validation/Encode URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple asp.net web forms page that simply intercepts http requests, pulls parameters from the query string, does some checking and redirects the request based on the parameters.

Lately, I have seem HttpRequestValidationException errors in the log. This is because the urls that we are taking in are not encoded, and we have Request.Validation set to true.

Now, I would like to stop getting this error, but I would still like to be protected from injection. I was thinking that I could turn off Request.Validation and simple encode the URL before I do anything with it. Is this a valid solution? Also, what type of encoding should I use? HTML encoding or url encoding? Im guessing HTML encoding will not protect against javascript or sql injection, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, I would like to stop getting this error

Is there any reason you would like to stop getting this?  This is good - it's telling you that a dangerous request was caught.  If you would like to just stop these hitting the logs, why not swallow the exception?

This would do the trick (Global.asax):

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    if(exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpRequestValidationException))
    {
        //ignore and don't write to log
    }

}
```

This also has the advantage of still logging all other exceptions.

Comment: Well the requests that I'm intercepting are coming from my system, so I know the requests arent really dangerous, they just arent encoded.